# Rest-Assured SSL connection

Tags: ssl, rest-assured

I need to setup secured connection, but I don't know how...
I have certificate (with password) in String that has something like this:

```
ewfMLr9P3xd6ZsUq3PEupoDN7XrWKf0TU  
.................................

bCUAdsdfvgss93kh8Zm2wtq1gYsa1hUnZ/
```

I put it to *.txt file, renamed it to *.crt, installed it to chrome and after that it started to work with Postman, but I don't undertand how to make it work with rest assured.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like cookies .you can use selenium to capture the cookies and later you can use these cookies for authentication.

Try to disable usual https verification aswell .

```
 RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
```